# Why react not render element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have following component

```
///assets/js/app.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="greeting">
          <h1> Hello World! </h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and html

```
<!--/templates/layout/app.html.eex-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Hello Sandbox!</title>
    <%= if Mix.env == :dev do %>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain:8080/styles.css">
    <% else %>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>">
    <% end %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">123</div>
     <%= if Mix.env == :dev do %>
      <script src="http://domain.ru:8080/app.js"></script>
    <% else %>
      <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My webpack config is here https://gist.github.com/Slavenin/8376458fe2e30ecc739fddf4a13b3be9 . When I open my page, all scripts are loaded from server, but nothing works. No errors or warnings thrown. Webpack compiles and outputs scripts. But on page I can see only 123. What's wrong?

[image: server console]
[image: dev tools]

Comment: I am assuming you are doing npm run start or yarn start or similar to compile the code

Comment: All compiled and loaded. But not eveal in browser.

Comment: don't you have js turned off in the browser? in devtools

Comment: no, js is enabled

Comment: Possible cached app.js file by browser. Or not pointing to the right file.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I can't comment yet, but could use [ReactDom.hydrate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) method instead of render.
It should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in `webpack.config.js` in https://gist.github.com/Slavenin/8376458fe2e30ecc739fddf4a13b3be9#file-webpack-conf-js-L9-L10 this broke javascript in browser. I do not know why, but it's true.